# Movement is not working pygame and it is telling me x is not defined even tho it is defined in line 64

Tags: python, pygame

My movement in pygame is not working and for some reason this error appears:
player = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/cuerv/Downloads/Player.png"(x, y, width, height)).convert()
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
even tho I have it defined in line 64. Also how can I know my rects are working. You can find part of the code in this website: https://pythonprogramming.altervista.org/platform-game-in-detail-part-1/?doing_wp_cron=1603309265.4902870655059814453125

```
from pygame.locals import *
import pygame
import sys
import glob
map1 = """wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
w                           w
w                           w
w                           w
w                           w
w                           
w                           d
w            p               
w                           
w                           w
w                           w
w                           w
w                           w
w                           w
w                           w
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww"""

#-----------------------------

door = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/cuerv/Downloads/Door.png")
door_rect = door.get_rect(center=(100, 250))

tile = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/cuerv/Downloads/Wall.png")
tile_rect = tile.get_rect(center=(100, 256))

player = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/cuerv/Downloads/Player.png"(x, y, width, height)).convert()
player_img.set_colorkey((255,255,255))
player_rect = player.get_rect(center=(100, 256))



def init_display():
    global screen, tile, door, player
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((480, 250))


def tiles(map1):
    global tile, door, player
    for y, line in enumerate(map1):
        #counts lines
        for x, c in enumerate(line):
            #counts caracters
            if c == "w":
                #caracter is w
                screen.blit(tile, (x * 16.18, y * 15))
            if c == "d":
                screen.blit(door, (x * 16.2, y * 15))
            if c == "p":
                screen.blit(player, (x * 16.2, y * 15))







width = 20
height = 20
vel = 10
x = 200
y = 200




map1 = map1.splitlines()
pygame.init()
init_display()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
    tiles(map1)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
            pygame.time.delay((5))

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()


    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 0:
        x -= vel


    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 500 - width:
        x += vel


    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > 0:
        y -= vel


    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y < 500 - height:
        y += vel




    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(120)
```

Comment: mostly you should define such constants in the first lines of code

Comment: but then a new error appears: player = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/cuerv/Downloads/Player.png"(x, y, width, height)).convert()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: You've accidently add `(x, y, width, height)` to  `player = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/cuerv/Downloads/Player.png"(x, y, width, height)).convert()`. Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You've accidently add `(x, y, width, height)` to a line in your code. This is very likely a copy/past issue. Remove it.

<s>`player = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/cuerv/Downloads/Player.png"(x, y, width, height)).convert()`</s>

```py
player = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/cuerv/Downloads/Player.png").convert()
```